Visual Studio Installer, Shared Components box greyed out
Recently I tried installing microsoft Visual Studio 2022 but in the installer the shared components box is grayed out and it uses the D drive below the gray. The thing is that my computer does not have a D drive. I am not going to pay 20 dollar to buy one. I have installed MSVS22 on a laptop before that also didn't have a D drive and it works just fine. I linked a video where the issue occures. Please help.
Thanks!
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ARw24xdjunbnQNg59
I have tried:

Restarting PC
Using a different MSVS22 version
Renaming the C drive to D (which made all other apps crash)
Opening in Admin
Watching YouTube tutorials (no one had the same problem)
Offline installation
Yell at my computer and tell it that it's a stupid box
I was hoping any of these would work.

